# ASP.net MVC 5 - How to redirect to action method from from session_end() event in Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I need to redirect to the home page when the session_end() method is called in my ASP.net MVC 5 application.

I have set the session timeout configuration on web.config 
And also I have added an action filter for if an action method is called when the session has been destroyed, the request is automatically redirected to the home page.

But now I need to automatically redirect to the login page when the session_end() method is called.

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string loginName2 = Environment.UserName;
        var allKiosks = new BLL.Services.svcInstanceKiosk().GetAllKiosks();
        var currentKiosk = allKiosks.Where(x => x.ComputerName.ToUpper() == loginName2.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
        new BLL.Services.svcKiosk().UpdateKioskLoginStatus(currentKiosk.ComputerName, false, "NA")
        Response.Redirect("/Home/Login");
    }
```

are there any solutions for `Response.Redirect("/Home/Login");` line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to do in Session_End, it is a server side event that triggers, there is no browser request/response involved here, so you cannot redirect the browser. You need to do this on the client.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. I was able to do this in client side auto refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to straight forward use something like the following in global.asax

```
Response.Redirect("/Home/Login");
```

I suggest using signalR to redirect users whose session has expired to a login page. You could do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) in order to handle and map users to connections. Then each time a user's session is over redirect him to a login page from from session_end in global.asax.